# Center align content to the right according to parent header

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a table using flexbox and I've run into an alignment issue. I want to be able to align my content to the right but having my header centered.

Example

```
____________
|   Test   |
|----------|
|     $1   |
|----------|
|   $312   |
|----------|
```

Here's an example structure that I have on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04Lzxqun/), any idea how can I achieve this using flexbox ?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/04Lzxqun/2/
Remove
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
from
.Parent div

```
.table{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.parent{
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-basis: 1 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.parent span{
  text-align: left !important;
}
.parent .header{
  text-align: center !important;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
}

.empty{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I asked